# pandas mean of the data within the same day of week

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dayofweek

I have a dataframe ranges from 2016 to 2019, shows the production numbers of a commodity in everyday. I have set the time as index and have converted it to date_time format.

> ```
>       Time         #Produced products     
>     2016-03-26    274
>     ....
>     2017-03-26    123
>     2017-02-27    245
>     ....
>     2018-03-26    282
>     ....
>     2019-03-23    296
> ```

Now, I would like to find the average daily production over these years, But in a way that is aware of the weekdays. So, since we have 52 weeks in a year, the output indexes will be: 1st Monday, 1st Tuesday,...., 52nd Saturday, 52nd Sunday.
For each index, it should find the mean of the produced numbers over the years 2016-2019.

I guess that I should use something such as groupby month and groupby dayofweek
I do not know how to implement it. Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is add another column to the dataframe using the `apply` function and a helper function -

*this helper function assumes that all entries in the `Time` column are in the python `datetime` format

```
def helper(my_date_time):
    week_list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday']
    week_number = my_date_time.isocalendar()[1]
    week_day = week_list[my_date_time.isocalendar()[2] - 1]
    return (week_day + str(week_number))
```

Once you have the helper function you can modify your dataframe to include the weekday and week number in another column-

```
df['week_number_day'] = df['Time'].apply(helper)
```

then you can use this to find the mean values you needed

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("week_number_day")
mean_df = grouped_df.mean()
mean_df = mean_df.reset_index()
print(mean_df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear @Karan_Shishoo for your wise response. It resolved my problem